# PHP CURL shows no "content_type" with Basic Auth

Tags: php, curl

The same code works ok in two enviroments (localhost and local develop) but not in the 3rd (prod). The 3rd is a VPS. I have to use basic auth with the API that I'm connecting.

This is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
//For basic auth
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "SomeUsername:AndItPass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
dump($curl);die();
```

The output of `dump($curl);die();` when works ok (like in localhost) is:

```
curl resource @61 ▼
  url: "http://XXXXX:8089/api/usuarios/login?perfil=2&rutPoem=76279543&rut=18863583"
  content_type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  http_code: 200
  header_size: 259
  request_size: 194
  filetime: -1
  ssl_verify_result: 0
  redirect_count: 0
  total_time: 0.022104
  namelookup_time: 3.9E-5
  connect_time: 0.008342
  pretransfer_time: 0.008463
  size_upload: 0.0
  size_download: 251.0
  speed_download: 11355.0
  speed_upload: 0.0
  download_content_length: 251.0
  upload_content_length: -1.0
  starttransfer_time: 0.022072
  redirect_time: 0.0
  redirect_url: ""
  primary_ip: "XXXXXXXX"
  certinfo: []
  primary_port: 8089
  local_ip: "192.168.4.108"
  local_port: 64594
}
```

But in the VPS I got this:

```
curl resource @345 ▼
  url: "http://XXXXX:8089/api/usuarios/login?perfil=2&rutPoem=76279543&rut=18863583"
  content_type: null
  http_code: 0
  header_size: 0
  request_size: 0
  filetime: -1
  ssl_verify_result: 0
  redirect_count: 0
  total_time: 0.200986
  namelookup_time: 0.000126
  connect_time: 0.0
  pretransfer_time: 0.0
  size_upload: 0.0
  size_download: 0.0
  speed_download: 0.0
  speed_upload: 0.0
  download_content_length: -1.0
  upload_content_length: -1.0
  starttransfer_time: 0.0
  redirect_time: 0.0
  redirect_url: ""
  primary_ip: ""
  certinfo: []
  primary_port: 0
  local_ip: ""
  local_port: 0
}
```

What is happening? I have "null" if I do a `dump(curl_error($curl));`

Comment: does the remote server need to white liste your IP?

Comment: I don't know. I've just sent an email asking that (due you comment and other threads that I've read). By the way, I have curl enabled in every environment.

Comment: curl is not the problem since it's returning a responce resource.

Comment: I have seen cURL blocked before based on user agent. Can you campare the useragent in local with the one in prod? Also, open up the dev tools in your browser and check out the headers and use cURL to replicate that.

Comment: Hmmm. I tested with www.google.com and curl works, but not with the API. Maybe is banned.

Comment: You can always use a proxy with cURL and see if that works.

Comment: Yes... I tested with a free web proxy and now works ok, but that's not the idea. I'll have to ask to the API guy to unblock my IP, FFS. @PatrickSimard if you want, post an answer with that, because in the end that was the reason behind my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of your question, looks to me like your IP is blocked. You can check that with loading a proxy inside your cURL request. If the request is not blocked then that means your server IP is blacklisted by the server firewall. You can ask the API owner to unblock your IP but also make sure you understand how you got blacklisted in the first place in order to make your app compliant with the remote server rules.

Comment: Thanks, `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://XXX:80");` did the trick.